# Why isn't my attempted solution working?

Tags: javascript

When I run the code in the console, the browser just stops working (am assuming stack overflow).

I've come up with several different algorithms for solving this problem, but I thought this one would not cause any SOs.

**The problem:**

> The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. The first ten terms would be:
>
> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
>
> Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:
>
> 1: 1
>
> 3: 1 3
>
> 6: 1,2,3,6
>
> 10: 1,2,5,10
>
> 15: 1,3,5,15
>
> 21: 1,3,7,21
>
> 28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
>
> We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.
>
> What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

**Failing solution:**

```
function divisors(n){
    var counter = 0;
    var triangle = 3;
    var triangle_add = 2;
    while (counter < n){
        for (var i = 1; i = triangle; i++){
            if (triangle % i === 0){
                counter++;
            }
        };
        if (counter < n){
            triangle_add++;
            triangle = triangle + triangle_add;
            counter = 0;
        };
    };
    return triangle;
};

console.log(divisors(501));
```

Comment: That won't have a stack overflow (stack overflows only usually occur when you have functions called recursively). Your flow is a little odd; usually you would simply return from an infinite loop instead of breaking out by convoluted conditions. As for why it fails, probably because you say `i = triangle` when I'm pretty sure you meant `i < triangle`

Comment: If it's not a stack overflow, do you know why my browser is jamming (newest version of Chrome on an older MacBook running Mountain Lion)?  I just made your adjustment (my original code reflected what you recommend) and that browser tab has stopped working.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not working because it's having to do an awful lot of calculation. In fact it's probably going beyond the range of a precise number (started getting into limited significant figures territory). You don't seem to have appreciated that the problem is posed specifically to be too difficult to solve by brute-force; you need to think about it first.

Comment: perhaps you mean i==triangle. If you use a single '=' you assign the value of triangle to i, while I think you want to compare the values, which should be done with i==triangle. Btw i'm running my own version as i type. It's been running for 5 minutes, and i'm currently at +- 390 ...

Comment: @Dave -> true. You know in advance that triangle 501! (faculty) is at least a solution. Perhaps it's faster to start at 501!, and go backwards

Comment: Actually I may stand corrected; I did a simple boundary limit and have a solution which runs very quickly. It might have a mistake though. You can see it here (spoilers, etc!) http://jsfiddle.net/CndWL/

Comment: I think there was a small mistake; updated http://jsfiddle.net/CndWL/1/

Comment: @dave Looks nice, i just don't understand it. How do you know it's the first triangle number?

Comment: @Entreco it essentially does the same thing your code does, but uses the knowledge that any divisor lower than the square root of the number will have a matching divisor greater than the square root. So it only needs to search a much smaller space for divisors. Also it calculates the i-th triangular number by the standard formula instead of adding to a variable each iteration, so that it can start from where it left off.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not working because, most probably, it is very slow. This problem can be solved much faster by the following method:

1. Find all the prime numbers smaller than some N (put, for example, N=100'000) using [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). It is quite fast.
2. As we know from elementary math each number can be written in the form **X=p1^i1*p2^i2*...*pn^in** where pj is prime number and ij is the power of corresponding prime number. The number of divisors of X is equal to **(i1+1)*(i2+1)*...*(in+1)** since that many different ways we can form a number which will be divisor of X. Having an array of prime numbers the number of divisors for X can be calculated quite fast (the code still has place to be optimized):

   ```
   int divisorCount(long long X)
   {
       int c = 1;
       for (int i = 0; PRIMES[i] <= X; ++i)
       {
           int pr = PRIMES[i];
           if (X % pr == 0)
           {
               int p = 1;
               long long r = X;
               while (r % pr == 0)
               {
                   r = r / pr;
                   ++p;
               }
               c *= p;
           }
       }
       return c;
   }
   ```
3. Iterate through all triangle numbers and count divisor numbers for them using the above function. The i-th triangle number is **i * (i + 1) / 2**, so no need to keep a variable, increment it and add it each time.